# Face Detection with OpenCV CascadeClassifier: .exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I am trying to write a simple program, that reads an image, detects a face on the image and marks the face with an rectangle on the image.
I use Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.9.

I use the cv::CascadeClassifier and haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml that are provided by OpenCV. Here is my Code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // OpenCV window I/O
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    //load image, in this case it's allready gray
    Mat img = imread("H:/BioID/BioID-FaceDatabase-V1.2/BioID_0000.pgm");

    Mat grayImg;   
    cvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //create vector of rectangles that will represent the faces
    vector<Rect> faces;

    CascadeClassifier* faseCascade = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    faseCascade->detectMultiScale(grayImg, faces);

    //draw rectangle on img; param: image, rectangle, color
    cv::rectangle(img, faces[0],Scalar(255,0,0),2); 

    //display image
    imshow("image", img);

    waitKey(0);     

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs properly, in the end it shows me the image with a blue rectangle around the face. But after I press a Key and the program is trying to close, it breaks.

The Output shows:

```
HEAP[myProgram.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00000004F9F30000, 00000004FC23ECE0 )
myProgram.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

If I comment out the detectMultiscale function and the draw rectangle function. The program runs without an error.

Does anybody have an idea, what I did wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add deallocate faseCascade before returning?

Comment: Any particular reason to use an outdated version of OpenCV? Debug or release mode? Which libraries did you link with?

Comment: @saurabheights When I do `delete faceCascade` before returning, I get the same Error Msg as before, only at the delete command instead at the end of the program.

Comment: @DanMašek There is no other reason, than that my predecessors used the 2.4.9 version and I continued to use it. I'm in the Debug mode.  I linked with these libraries: opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
opencv_gpu249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_nonfree249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_photo249d.lib
opencv_stitching249d.lib
opencv_ts249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_videostab249d.lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had the wrong path to the opencv bin folder in my Environment Variables.
I recently stopped using Visual Studio 2010 and started using VS2012 and forgot to adapt the path.
I had to change it from
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin;
to
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin;
and restart the computer.

Now everything seems to work properly.